# regex to compare github links and list repos which end with the same name but have different owner

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

I frequently clone  github repos and try them  in my computer. Unfortunately github repos can have the same name as another user's repo name.

For example:

```
https://github.com/user1/app_name.git
https://github.com/user2/app_name.git
```

When I clone a repo in terminal like

```
git clone https://github.com/user1/app_name.git
```

it saves the repo under name after the slash like

```
app_name
```

If I clone the second repo, I get `the repo exists` message and cloning repo aborts.

I just noticed that, and I want to know which repos aborted in that way.

To find them I did something like

```
history |  grep github.com
```

but this lists hundreds of lines and it's difficult to pick up the repos with the same `app_name` and different `user_name`.

It must be a very easy task for a regex query,  but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
history | grep -o 'github\.com.*' | tr '/' ' ' | sort -k3 | uniq | uniq -D -f2
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -o 'github\.com.*'` get the lines that include `github.com` and trim off the start of the line (like the number of the item in the history etc) to make it easier to deal with the fields
- `tr '/' ' '` change `/` into spaces because `uniq` doesn't have an option to set a non-whitespace delimiter...
- `sort -k3` sort the lines using the third (last) field, putting the lines with the same `app_name.git` together
- `uniq` remove duplicate lines
- `uniq -D -f2` ignoring the first two fields, print only the duplicate lines, (so only print the line if there is more than one instance of `app_name` after removing completely identical lines, indicating that there are multiple users for the same `app_name`)

If you want to avoid the command itself appearing in the output, you can pipe from `grep -o 'github\.com.*' ~/.bash_history` instead of `history | grep -o 'github\.com.*'` (although this won't include commands from the current session)